# Open a qcombobox and related signal

Tags: c++, python, qt, signals-slots, qcombobox

I wrote the following connection:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.comboBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("foobar")), lambda:  self.materialsInstance.addToComboBox_Insert(self))
```

According to my code, i wrote `foobar` as `signal` , i need to when user click or open `QComboBox` `slot self.materialsInstance.addToComboBox_Insert`  will be `emitted`.But i don't know related `Signal`

*Notes:* My `QComboBox` is empty.

**My question** is, What's related `signal` for open or click on `QComboBox`?

Comment: BTW, why do you need it, I didn't get what you want to do with that SIGNAL

Comment: There are only signals for hovering, selecting or changing an entry in the combo box. Maybe [installEventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#installEventFilter) can be used to achieve whatever you want to do

Comment: So you want to insert something to combobox at the same moment the combobox is clicked? That's not a good practice...